# React Native OpenTok Subscriber FullScreen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, opentok

Hello everyone I'm using `opentok-react-native": "^0.20.3"` with  `react-native: "0.61.5"` .

The issue is OTSubscriber component zooms in when used with style width and height of 100%. I want to use OTSubscriber on fullscreen.

I'm trying to build a screen with live stream(OTSubscriber) in fullscreen fit 1:1.

After all I couldn't find any solutions, I tried using `resolution` in subscriber properties in `OTSubscriber`.

I'm using iOS and developing with react-native. Here is the sample code:

```
<OTSession
      apiKey={this.state.apiKey}
      sessionId={this.state.sessionId}
      token={this.state.token}
      options={{
        iceConfig: {
          transportPolicy: 'all',
          includeServers: 'all',
          customServers: [],
        },
      }}>
      <OTSubscriber
        properties={subscriberProperties}
        style={{width: deviceWidth, height: deviceHeight * 0.5}}
        // style={{width: 400,
        //   height: 300,}}
        eventHandlers={subscriberEventHandlers}
      />
</OTSession>
```

Comment: Hi can you share whether youre using android/ios or if the behavior is the same and a code snippet

Comment: I'm using iOS but developing with react-native so both should work. I added samples and information that you required in main question.

Comment: Hi abdulajet I provided sample code above.

Comment: Can you try with  `style={{width: '100%',height: '100%'}}`

Comment: On a different note, remove the iceConfig property if you are not using it ;)

Comment: See a working example: https://github.com/enricop89/multiparty-video-react-native

Comment: Hi enricop89, i tried to add style={{width: '100%',height: '100%'}} but the stream is ZOOMED IN. But i want to stream to be normal. iceConfig is crucial for android opentok